# Find all docs but if some docs have a same value get the latest one

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'll try to explain with sample data. A user can make any amount of reviews but I only want to return the latest one by a reviewer.

```
{   
    id : 1
    name : "John",
    review : "only one review"
    dateCreated : 2017-02-23 02:35:11.420Z
}
{   
    id : 3
    name : "Sam"
    review : "second entered"
    dateCreated : 2017-02-23 02:41:42.300Z
}
{   
    id : 2
    name : "Sam",
    review : "fist enterd"
    dateCreated : 2017-02-23 02:36:32.150Z
}
```

A .find() should return the docs with id 1 and id 3. Because there is only one made by John and the one with id 3 was the last one made by Sam.

Is there a query for this?

My actual project is more difficult because instead of `name` I have `userId`and `anonId`. Those fields have values that are objects Ids. and the most complicated part is that a doc does not contain both. Either it contains a `userId` or an `anonId`

So I think I would need an or condition to maybe. anonId or userId

maybe you can give me ideas about this too.

EDIT:

my actual data looks more like this. It is more complicated.

```
{
    anonId : ObjectId("58ae4f934a7d2b2490e8f99c")
    review : review made by an anoymous user
    dateCreated : 2017-02-23 02:35:11.420Z
}
{
    anonId : ObjectId("58ae4f934a7d2b2490e8f99c")
    review : second review made by anonymous user
    dateCreated : 2017-02-23 05:35:11.420Z
}
{
    userId : ObjectId("58ae4a5f4a7d2b2490e8f996")
    review : first review made by authenticated user
    dateCreated : 2017-02-22 05:35:11.420Z
}
{
    userId : ObjectId("58ae4a5f4a7d2b2490e8f996")
    review : second review made by authenticated user
    dateCreated : 2017-02-25 05:35:11.420Z
}

{
    userId : ObjectId("58ae5fc7a467cf23947833c8")
    review : This will be returened because no other review has this userID
    dateCreated : 2017-02-25 05:35:11.420Z
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a descending `$sort` on `dateCreated` and `$group` by `userId` or `anonId` :

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    $sort: {
        "dateCreated": -1
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        ref: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $gt: ["$userId", null] },
                then: "$userId",
                else: "$anonId"
            }
        },
        document: "$$ROOT"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$ref",
        document: {
            "$first": "$document"
        }
    }
}])
```

Note that the condition used in the `$project` stage is to check if `userId` exist else set `ref` to `anonId`

[Here](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/a8b90ff77eede35f370d2988f7bfc84a) is a gist

Comment: well lets say I have 20 fields / paths. I should get the first for all of them

Comment: I've updated with your real usecase (with `userId` and `anonId`) and using `$$ROOT` as a nested document to take care of all your fields

Comment: I think this makes populating the `userId` `anonId` fields more difficult. can I do populate after this? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: cool. I think I could do it. `..then(aggr =>{
    Review.populate(aggr, [{path : "document.userId", model : "User"}, {path : "document.anonId", model : "Anon"}])
        .then(populated =>{
            console.log(JSON.stringify(populated))
        })
}))`. `aggr` was returned from the aggregation

Comment: Can you share your mongoose model ?